# http.createServer in nodeJS doesnt work in company network

Tags: node.js

I am a beginner programmer so my technical skills are low in general.

The following code:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World!');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

Runs without a problem on my home network.

But doesnt run on my Business Network.

Code in Atom:

[image]

Headers I get back after running in the browser:

[image]

If it helps, we use a Windows server 2012 for the network and I have access in it.

Is this really related to the server?

Comment: the URL should be `http://localhost:1337` it is a port not part of the path `1337`

Comment: are you behind a proxy? if so be sure to set http_proxy ad https_proxy environment variables

Comment: It works now. Thank you for the fast reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Yerken mentioned, your URL should be http://localhost:1337, and not http://localhost/1337.

In your code, you are listening to port 1337, but by default, the browser tries to access port 80 if no port is specified. That means localhost/1337 is trying to access port 80, and not 1337 which you are listening to.

So change the URL to :1337 as oposed to /1337 and it should work :)

Happy programming!